# Working with multi threads in Map Reduce job

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, mapreduce

I notice the addzone have asking for knowing both Map-Reduce and Java Multi-Threading - I don't see how them both exists in the same project.
Could someone give me an example when do we need to combining both Map-Reduce and Multi-Threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop a large system there are subsystems requiring different technologies to apply.

Comment: could you give an exmpale in somthing we both know like how will it be existed in Facebook or YouTube ?